# Compile error during compilation of my simple Java file

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I have written a simple java program mentioned in below. Unfortunately a compile error occurs.

```
class String {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

The following comes out during compilation at command prompt:

c:\Java>java String
Error: Main method not found in class String, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

It wasn't working for any of my programs, not even this simple one! Why is this?

***EDIT:***

Now I have:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.String.*;

class incogn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

And its not working. Why isn't that working?

It says the exact thing as before.

What you said with the Java.lang.String[] works, but why won't this? And why haven't I needed to put any of this on before?

Comment: Why did you call the class `String`?

Comment: What's not working? What's the error? And did you remember to rename your .java file?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because you are using the name `String` for your class, colliding with `java.lang.String`; in other words, you have written that your main method takes instances of your class as input, rather than the one that the main method needs to take, namely `java.lang.String`.  Try either

1. Renaming your class
2. Changing your signature to `public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {`

Comment: The 2nd point it's useless. The problem is having a `String` class. The JVM complains because there is a `String` class already loaded (yes, the `java.lang.String` class).

Comment: I disagree. In fact, the compiler does not complain. It's the VM that complains, because there is no main(java.lang.String[]). I think that #2 is the real point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, giving your class name `String` and then call `main(String[] args)` is ambiguous, if it means `java.lang.String` or your newly defined class, but with java scope rules, it will use your, unless otherwise declared.

---

**Update after edit**

There's no `java.lang.String` ***package***, but it is a ***class***. Therefore, you can't say

```
import java.lang.String.*;
```

By adding the "`.*`" the compiler understands that this refers to some package `String`.

One exception, is the static import, but this is not what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call your class String, it will conflict with the java class String.

Or,  you can change your code to:

```
class String {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
         System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't create a java file named "String" as it is the java library class in java.lang.String
2. Make the class as public

So, write your source code as below:

```
public class StringDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

Compile it now. I believe it would work well.

Answer (score 0):

**1) The class should be `public`**

**2) Avoid to call you class `String`, as it has the duplicate name with `java.lang.String` (You still can, but not good). Otherwise, your main method is having wrong type of arguments.**

**3) You don't have to explicitly import from `java.lang` package.**

---

```
public class String {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
         System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("stre");
    }
}
```

Try to use the second form.